# Union All with Join

Tags: sql

I'm trying to perform a join after Union All. Separately the 2 queries work but I haven't been able to piece together the join. The Unioned query needs to then be joing by assigned_user_id from the accounts table join

```
(SELECT 
       c.[id]
      ,c.[assigned_user_id]
      ,c.[assigned_user_name]
  FROM DB.[Sales] AS s
  WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1

  UNION ALL 

SELECT 
       m.[id]
      ,m.[assigned_user_id]
      ,m.[assigned_user_name]
  FROM [DB].[Units] AS u
  WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1)


 (SELECT 
       a.[id]
      ,a.[assigned_user_name]
      ,u.[id] 
  FROM [DB].[Accounts] AS a
  JOIN [DB].[Users] AS u  ON a.[assigned_user_name] = u.[full_name]
  WHERE a.[IsCurrent] = 1 AND u.IsCurrent = 1)
```

Comment: TAG your specific RDBMS.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what are the existing tables vs the union result: you say `The Unioned query needs to then be joing (...) from the accounts table join` but where does this `Users` table come from? Anyway, do you mean how to implement a [cte](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/)? Btw please tag your dbms

Comment: your unioned queries that start `SELECT ,c.[id]` is a syntax error. It's also not clear how you are expecting to join these two separate queries, however presumably you're using SQL Server (given the `[]` delimiters) so just define them as two CTEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make them subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT * -- something here, not sure what you need
  FROM (SELECT s.[id]
              ,s.[assigned_user_id]
              ,s.[assigned_user_name]
          FROM DB.[Sales] AS s
          WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1

          UNION ALL 

        SELECT u.[id]
              ,u.[assigned_user_id]
              ,u.[assigned_user_name]
          FROM [DB].[Units] AS u
          WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1
     ) unioned
  JOIN (SELECT a.[id] as assigned_account_id 
             , a.[assigned_user_name]
             , u.[id] as assigned_user_id -- not sure if this is the column you want to join on
          FROM [DB].[Accounts] AS a
          JOIN [DB].[Users] AS u  ON a.[assigned_user_name] = u.[full_name]
         WHERE a.[IsCurrent] = 1 AND u.IsCurrent = 1
     ) account_user
    ON unioned.assigned_user_id = account_user.assigned_user_id
```

I personally don't like subqueries this long and would have written it using CTEs:

```
WITH unioned AS (
    SELECT s.[id]
          ,s.[assigned_user_id]
          ,s.[assigned_user_name]
      FROM DB.[Sales] AS s
     WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1

      UNION ALL 

    SELECT u.[id]
          ,u.[assigned_user_id]
          ,u.[assigned_user_name]
      FROM [DB].[Units] AS u
     WHERE [IsCurrent] = 1
),
account_users AS (
    SELECT a.[id] as assigned_account_id 
         , a.[assigned_user_name]
         , u.[id] as assigned_user_id -- not sure if this is the column you want to join on
      FROM [DB].[Accounts] AS a
      JOIN [DB].[Users] AS u  ON a.[assigned_user_name] = u.[full_name]
     WHERE a.[IsCurrent] = 1 AND u.IsCurrent = 1
)
SELECT * -- something here, not sure what you need
  FROM unioned
  JOIN account_user
    ON unioned.assigned_user_id = account_user.assigned_user_id
```